# Queryset filter with three-deep nested models (multiple one-to-many relationships)

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to figure out how to filter some queries in Django with my models setup something like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class TeamPosition(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Player(models.Model):
    teamposition = models.ForeignKey(TeamPosition)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    joined_date = models.DateField()
    left_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I'd like to find querysets that answer these questions (moved below for clarity):

If I start at the TeamPosition objects it is much easier to figure out (but doesn't give me a queryset of Teams).

Sample Data set:

Object set 1:

```
Team(name="Apples")
    TeamPosition(team="Apples", description="Forward")
        Player(team="Apples", teamposition="Forward", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=null, person="Bob")
    TeamPosition(team="Apples", description="Defense")
        Player(team="Apples", teamposition="Defense", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=2015-01-01, person="John")
        Player(team="Apples", teamposition="Defense", joined_date="2015-01-01", left_date=2017-01-01, person="Paul")
    TeamPosition(team="Apples", description="Goalie")
        Player(team="Apples", teamposition="Goalie", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=2015-01-01, person="Jane")
```

Object set 2:

```
Team(name="Pears")
    TeamPosition(team="Pears", description="Forward")
        Player(team="Pears", teamposition="Forward", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=null, person="Carol")
    TeamPosition(team="Pears", description="Defense")
        Player(team="Pears", teamposition="Defense", joined_date="2015-01-01", left_date=2017-01-01, person="Bill")
    TeamPosition(team="Pears", description="Goalie")
        Player(team="Pears", teamposition="Goalie", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=null, person="Susan")
```

Object set 3:

```
Team(name="Oranges")
    TeamPosition(team="Oranges", description="Forward")
    TeamPosition(team="Oranges", description="Forward")
    TeamPosition(team="Oranges", description="Goalie")
```

Object set 4:

```
Team(name="Bananas")
    TeamPosition(team="Bananas", description="Forward")
        Player(team="Bananas", teamposition="Forward", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date=null, person="Joe")
    TeamPosition(team="Bananas", description="Defense")
        Player(team="Bananas", teamposition="Defense", joined_date="2015-01-01", left_date=2017-01-01, person="Angela")
    TeamPosition(team="Bananas", description="Goalie")
        Player(team="Bananas", teamposition="Goalie", joined_date="2014-01-01", left_date="2016-09-30", person="Kelly")
```

So based on those objects, I'd expect the following results:

- Which Teams have available TeamPositions? (available meaning a TeamPosition without a current Player)

  `Queryset should return Object 1 (Apples) and Object 3 (Oranges)`
- Which Teams have all TeamPositions full with current Players? (the opposite of above) (current meaning a Player that has either no left_date or a left_date in the future)

  `Queryset should return Object 2 (Pears) and Object 4 (Bananas)`
- Which Teams will have an empty TeamPosition in 30 days?

  `Queryset should return Object 4 (Bananas)`

Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Note: Previously had a car example (hence first response), but it seemed unclear so created a better example

Answer (score 0):

<strike>One question before answering: Is the line `carmodel = models.ForeignKey(Model)` ok? or should it be `ForeignKey(CarModel)` instead?</strike>

Try this query (this should give you all CarCompany objects whose CarModel's ModelYear's `last_availability` date is in the future:

```
from datetime import datetime
CarCompany.objects.filter(carmodel__modelyear__last_availability__gte=datetime.now())
```

In order to check both whether `last_availability` is in the future or blank/null I would use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
CarCompany.objects.filter(Q(carmodel__modelyear__last_availability__gte=datetime.now()) |
                          Q(carmodel__modelyear__last_availability__isnull=True))
```

For your second example, I can't think but in the same query (It answers your questions `Which Teams have open TeamPositions?` and `Which Teams will have an empty TeamPosition in 30 days`)

But I'm not sure what do you mean by `Which Teams have no TeamPositions without current Players?` If you could explain it a bit...

```
Team.objects.filter(Q(teamposition__player__left_date__gte=datetime.now()) |
                    Q(teamposition__player__left_date__isnull=True) |
```

Comment: You're right should have been CarModel. I'll try this out..!

Comment: Ran a quick test, removed the exact='' (I think dates are always null when blank, which django reminded me) and added a distinct(). However, I ended up getting all of my test objects back (should have been about half of them). I'm editing my question to add a different example set of classes that might be more clear.

Comment: I can't see why that query does not work. I updated my answer, anyway. Could you clarify what does `Which Teams have no TeamPositions without current Players?` in the second example mean?

Comment: i.e. If a Team had 2 TeamPlayers one of which had a Player object with a joined_date of yesterday and no left_date, and but the other TeamPlayer object had either no Player associated with it, or a Player with a left_date of last year.

Comment: The query works... it just returns a queryset of all my test data. In theory it should only return the CarCompany objects that have CarModels with ModelYears with either null last_availability or last_availability in the future. I had one test data where there was a CarCompany with a CarModel and no ModelYear objects which was included, but when I created a ModelYear object that expired long before it was removed from the set. I think it trips up when there are multiple CarModels.

Comment: What do you refer to when you mention `TeamPlayer` (two comments above), are you refering to `TeamPosition`? I got lost.
Anyway, could you provide some example objects (three should be enough) and the query result you expect?

Comment: Apologies, I did mean `TeamPosition`. Sure, let me map out a few objects in the question.